# EJB @Startup on Jetty

Tags: java, ejb, jetty

I need to make this code (that works with JBoss) run with Jetty:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.picketlink.idm.PartitionManager;
import org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Realm;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class PicketLinkStartup {

  @Inject
  private PartitionManager partitionManager;

  @PostConstruct
  public void workaround() {
    /*
     * This forces the partition manager to be loaded on app startup. Without
     * this, it is possible for a FailedAuthenticationException to leave
     * picketlink in a bad state where the default partition is no longer
     * accessible.
     */
    partitionManager.getPartition(Realm.class, Realm.DEFAULT_REALM);
  }

}
```

I need to have this `PicketLinkStartup` run at Jetty startup. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss is a full EE application server with an EJB container while Jetty is just a servlet container. To use session beans in your application you need to deploy into an EJB container.

You could try integrating [OpenEJB](http://openejb.codehaus.org/index.html) with Jetty but no guarantee that it'll work.